# Map 2 Arrays to produce a desired string

Tags: php, arrays

So i have two arrays and i want to map 0th key of first array with 0th key of second array and both array could have n number of keys ,so that the final Result which would be a string should look something like mentioned below

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)

Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 10
)
```

Result--

```
1:5,2:10
```

i tried this--
which gives output

```
:1:5,1:10,2:5,2:10,
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Post your attempts

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for code formatting help.

Comment: You mean _map 0th *value* of first array with 0th *value* of second array_ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit verbose but will handle if both input arrays are 2 different lengths.

```
<?php

$array_one = [1,2];
$array_two = [5,10];

// Array we work with to push the merged data too,
$array_result = [];

foreach($array_one as $index => $value) {

   $array_result[$index] = $value;

}

foreach($array_two as $index => $value) {

  // If the first number was set from the $array_one iteration then concatenate ':' and this $array_two_value, else simply add this $array_two_value.
  if(isset($array_result[$index])) {
     $array_result[$index] .= ':' . $value;
  }
  else {
    $array_result[$index] .= $value;
  }

}

echo implode(',',$array_result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
// Function which concats two given strings with ':' and returns
function concatValues($v1,$v2)
{
  return($v1.':'.$v2);
}

// Input arrays
$first_input_array = Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 );
$second_input_array = Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 10 );

// array_map to concat corresponding values from the two input arrays
$output = array_map('concatValues',
                    array_values($first_input_array), 
                    array_values($second_input_array)
                   );

// Implode to get comma separated string
$output = implode(',', $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

To map it into another array, you can do it like this:

```
<?php
    $a1 = [1,2,3,4,5];

    $a2 = [5,4,3,2,1];

    $a3 = [];

    foreach($a1 as $k => $v) {

        $a3[$v] = null;

        if(array_key_exists($k, $a2)) {
            $a3[$v] = $a2[$k];
        }
    }

    print_r($a3);
```

it get the requested string you may do it like this:

```
<?php
    $a1 = [1,2,3,4,5];

    $a2 = [5,4,3,2,1];

    $a3 = [];

    foreach($a1 as $k => $v) {

        if(array_key_exists($k, $a2)) {
            $a3[] = $v . ':' . $a2[$k];
        }
    }

    echo implode(',', $a3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting loops which is not what you want to do here.

I will assume that both arrays have the same number of elements so that we can make a simple solution.

```
$output = '';
if ( count($a1) == count($a2) ) {
    foreach ( $a1 as $i => $val1 ) {
        // put the comma if this is not the first one
        if ( $i > 0 ) $output .= ',';
        $output .= "{$val}:{$a2[$i]}";
    }
}
echo $output;
```